# Parametrization of 2d rotating surface triangle from a physics flux problem

Tags: surfaces, rotations, parametrization

So the problem is that we have an equilateral triangle (side $\mathrm{a}$) with it's center in the origin that is rotating $\omega\hat{z}$. The magnetic field is in the $\hat{x}$ direction (not needed for my question) and I need to find the flux (trivial). The problem looks thusly: [image]

So, solving problems like that is not hard, but the hardest part is finding the correct parameterization for the $\vec{r}$ which describes our surface through which we are finding the flux. Now in the solutions the parameterization stated is the following:
$$\vec{r} = \frac{a}{2}\xi\hat{n}(t) + \frac{a}{2}\eta\hat{m}$$ where $\hat{m}$ describes the side that is at the $\pi/3$ with respect to $\hat{n}$ and $\xi,\eta$ are in range $[-1,1]$...so...
$$\hat{n}(t) = -\mathrm{sin}(\omega t)\hat{x} + \mathrm{cos}(\omega t)\hat{y}$$
This I understand.
The problematic part for me is the "vertical" part.
$$\hat{m} = -\frac{1}{2}\hat{n} + \frac{1\sqrt{3}}{2}\hat{z}$$

Now the solution is then simplified by introducing:
$$\xi = 2u-1\\   
\eta = 2v-1$$
... and then when you go look for the surface differential (trivial) you derivate $\vec{r}$ with respect to $\mathrm{u}$ and $\mathrm{v}$ and get
$$\mathrm{d}^2r=[\frac{a^2\sqrt{3}}{2}[\mathrm{cos}(\omega t)\hat{x}+\mathrm{sin}(\omega t)\hat{y}]-\frac{a^2}{2}sin(\omega t)\hat{z}]\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$$
And finally, to find flux $\vec{B}\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{A}$, one only has to realize that the area that describes the triangle is in:
$$u \in [0,1] \\
v \in [0,1-u]$$

I understand the $\hat{n}(t)$ but I can not figure out the $v \in [0,1-u]$ and $\hat{m}$

Comment: Is there a typo in the equation expressing $\hat{m}$ in terms of $\hat{n}$? It appears that $\hat{m}$ has been written as the sum of a vector and a scalar.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the $\hat{z}$

Comment: And of course, in $t=0$ the triangle is in the $y-z$ plane

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand the parametrisation given in the question, so I will give a parametrisation and work things out from there.

---

The typical way to parametrise a triangle with vertices given by position vectors $\vec{r}_1$, $\vec{r}_2$ and $\vec{r}_3$ is via

$$ p(\lambda, \mu) := \vec{r}_1 + \lambda(\vec{r}_2 - \vec{r}_1) + \mu (\vec{r}_3 - \vec{r}_1), \lambda, \mu \in [0,1]  \text{ and } \lambda \leq \mu. $$

For all $t$, denote by $\vec{r}_1(t)$ be the position vector at time $t$ of the vertex of the triangle that initially has a negative $y$ coordinate, $\vec{r}_2(t)$ the (constant) position vector at time $t$ of the vertex that remains fixed under the rotation, and $r_3(t)$ the position vector at time $t$ of the vertex initially positioned with a positive $y$ coordinate.

Initially ($t = 0$), the position vectors of the vertices are given by

\begin{align} 
\vec{r}_1(0) &= \left(0, -\frac a 2, -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6} a\right), \\  
\vec{r}_2(0) &= \left(0, 0, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} a\right), \text{ and } \\
\vec{r}_3(0) &= \left(0, \frac a 2, -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6} a\right).
\end{align}

The positions of the vertices at time $t$ are given by rotating the initial positions by an angle $\omega t$ about the $z$-axis. Hence, for all $1 \leq i \leq 3$ and times $t$ we have $$\vec{r}_i(t) = R_z(\omega t) \vec{r}_i(0), $$ where $R_z( \omega t)$ is the [matrix corresponding to a rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) about the $z$-axis by an angle $\omega t$. After calculating the $\vec{r}_i(t)$, we can give a parametrisation $p_t$ of the triangle at time $t$ using the method outlined at the beginning, which turns out to be
$$ p_t(\lambda, \mu) = \frac{a}{2}\left(\lambda + 2 \mu - 1\right) \hat{n}(t) + \frac{\sqrt{3} a}{6} \left( 3 \lambda - 1 \right) \hat{z}, \lambda , \mu \in [0,1], \lambda \leq \mu.$$

Using the convention that the unit normal vector to the triangle is initially $\hat{x}$, the flux $\Phi(t)$ of the vector field $\vec{B}(x,y,z)$ through the triangle at time $t$ is equal to

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^\mu \vec{B}\left(p_t(\lambda, \mu)\right) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial p_t}{\partial \mu} \times \frac{\partial p_t}{\partial \lambda} \right) d\lambda d\mu.$$ Running through the calculations, we get that

$$ \Phi(t) = \frac{\sqrt{3} a^2}{2} \int_0^1 \int_0^\mu \vec{B}\left(p_t(\lambda, \mu)\right) \cdot  \left( \cos(\omega t) \hat{x} + \sin(\omega t) \hat{y} \right) d\lambda d\mu.$$

---

I apologise that I can't be of help interpreting the solution referred to in the question, but hopefully this gives you a gist of how to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I will go through your solution. The problem is that the solution that is given for this problem doesn't have any intermediary steps. The parameterization was "God-given" and not quite clear. Funny thing is, that the parameterization is correct because if you actually "brute force" check the parameterization like two "FOR" loops (xi and eta) and take random numbers between -1 and 1 for a given $\omega t$, you will get the correct position vector inside the triangle. It's hard to understand but correct

Comment: I thank you for your help btw. (with an upvote)